# Irony: StringLiteral without StartEndSymbol

Tags: c#, dsl, irony

I'm using the Irony DSL framework to parse a language. That language allows strings to be written without quotes ("), even if they contain special characters like dot (.) or minus (-).

If I editthe text files I get, so the strings have quotes around them, they can be parsed just fine. However, I want to read the files as they are. How can I make Irony parse a string without setting a StartEndSymbol?

I'm using the current version of Irony (2012_03_15).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Sample SQL grammar. It allows identifiers to contain `'.'` such as `SELECT a.x FROM table`.  And in this case the 'Id' will be a list with your delimeter.

```
var dot = ToTerm(".");
var dash = ToTerm("-");
var Id_simple = TerminalFactory.CreateSqlExtIdentifier(this, "id_simple"); //covers normal identifiers (abc) and quoted id's ([abc d], "abc d")
Id.Rule = MakePlusRule(Id, dot, Id_simple) | MakePlusRule(Id, dash, Id_simple)

 //Covers simple identifiers like abcd, and also quoted versions: [abc d], "abc d".
    public static IdentifierTerminal CreateSqlExtIdentifier(Grammar grammar, string name) {
      var id = new IdentifierTerminal(name);
      StringLiteral term = new StringLiteral(name + "_qouted");
      term.AddStartEnd("[", "]", StringOptions.NoEscapes);
      term.AddStartEnd("\"", StringOptions.NoEscapes);
      term.SetOutputTerminal(grammar, id); //term will be added to NonGrammarTerminals automatically 
      return id;
    }
```

If it works for SQL, it should work for you.

Comment: +1: nice find! What the OP is looking for specifically is I think `'TerminalFactory.CreateSqlExtIdentifier'`

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to clarify. 
Declaration of "id" varibale in CreateSqlExtIdentifier class: "//Covers simple identifiers like abcd, and also quoted versions: [abc d], "abc d" and underscores and digits, *but not more*. That fact, that SQL parser embraces dots like parts of "id" - is the result of the down following Rule: 
`**"Id.Rule = MakePlusRule(Id, dot, Id_simple);"**`
As a solution, you can declare special characters (if there are not many) and make your custom Rule, that will enclose possible apperences in code. 

For example:
    `specialSymbols.Rule = ToTerm(".") | "-" | ...etc.;`
    `myId.Rule = id_simple | specialSymbols;`
    `myIds.Rule = MakePlusRule(myIds<,Delimiter if nedeed>,myId);`

Best Regards, Dionis.

Answer (score 0):

I also would like to see the proper oway of doing this. Currently I just use IdentifierTerminal by setting the necessary extra characters in its constructor.